# javascript Time formatting behaving strangely

Tags: javascript, date-formatting

I ran into a bizarre issue with the time formatting in js

```
function getClockInTime() {
    var now = new Date();

    var hour = parseInt(now.format("HH"));
    var timeString = now.format('h:MM:ss') + " " + (hour > 12 ? "PM" : "AM");

    return timeString;
}
```

On my boss' machine, the above function displays the time as hour, minute, and seconds. On my machine this formatting displays it as the hour, the month, and seconds and to get minutes I do h:mm:ss instead which displays hour, month, second on his.

Any theories as to why this could be happening? I think it may be because mine is running AMD hardware and his is Intel, so they could do the internal clock stuff a bit differently.

Moreover, would there be a way of formatting this so the time is hour, minute, second universally on all machines?

Thanks

Comment: What browsers do you and your boss run? They could be the source of the difference.

Comment: I believe he uses Chrome and I use IE for my testing. However, I just tested it out in Chrome and it's working fine for me still

Comment: Tell your boss to clear his cache. If he's using Chrome the shortcut is CTRL-F5

Comment: Where is '.format()' coming from? Is it a custom function of yours? Library?

Comment: Would caching cause this issue though? This seems like more of an internal clock thing.

Comment: @RyanJ: You have to understand that Javascript lives in your browser. The browser implements how JS should be dealt with. You say you use IE, well, there you go. IE is crap (imo ofc). The source of the problem might be because `.format` (which is new to me btw), might not be completly implemented in IE yet. Re-write your method to parse timestamp to hhmmss instead (manualy).

Comment: Yeah I know IE is crap lol, but it's just what I have to test with unfortunately. Yeah parsing may work, i'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

So turns out if you use a custom library for javascript called datejs https://code.google.com/p/datejs/, it solves this problem for you, i just put my formatting in the custom .toString() included with this library and the hh:mm:ss appears as it should on both machines.

So it looks like this now:

```
function getClockInTime() {
    var now = new Date();

    var hour = parseInt(now.format("HH"));
    var timeString = now.toString('hh:mm:ss tt');

    return timeString;
}
```

And this will output the current time with am or pm.